# Why is this integral (that looks complicated) so easy to evaluate?

Tags: integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions, improper-integrals

I encounter the following integral during Statistics lecture and the professor quickly solved it as if he assumed we know that this integral is easy so solve:

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} xe^{-(1-t)x} dx = \frac{1}{(1-t)^2}$$

I suspect that this involves a probability distribution but I do not know which. Why is this integral so easy to solve? I know I must have been missing something.

Comment: If all else fails, the integral is quite easily solved using integration by parts.

Comment: The solution holds only as long as $t<1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each $\lambda<0$,\begin{align}\int_0^\infty xe^{\lambda x}\,\mathrm dx&=\left[x\frac{e^{\lambda x}}\lambda\right]_{x=0}^{x=\infty}-\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{\lambda x}}\lambda\,\mathrm dx\\&=-\left[\frac{e^{\lambda x}}{\lambda^2}\right]_{x=0}^{x=\infty}\\&=\frac1{\lambda^2}.\end{align}

Comment: How can the mean of exponential rv be negative

Comment: Thank you for the answer! May I also know why can we be sure  $xe^{-\lambda x} $ always converges to some number as $x$ tends to infinity?

Comment: By the rule of lhopitals

Comment: @Neymar I see. Thanks.